# I need to add a third appendchild() inside a dom div

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have the appendChild(detail) appear after the appendChild(image) but it doesn't show up in the browser.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn2").addEventListener("click", hey);

function hey(){     
    for (i = 1; i < radio.length; i++){
        f = radio[i].image ;

        var item = document.createElement('div');
        item.id = "box";
        item.className = "dell";
        item.style.height = "140px";
        detail = document.createElement('div');
        detail.className = "space";
        image = document.createElement('img');
        image.id = "pic";
        image.className = "dell3";
        image.setAttribute("src", f);

        document.getElementById('case').appendChild(item).appendChild(image).appendChild(detail);                                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your HTML too please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the appended node. It's not *chainable* in the way that you think.  In your code, `item` is appended to `'case'`, `image` to `item` and `detail` to `image`.  Since `image` is an `<img>` element that should not have children, `detail` is not displayed.

The solution is to append each item separately to a document fragment, then append the document fragement to case.

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var item = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
item.id = "box";
item.className = "dell";
item.style.height = "140px";
var detail = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
detail.className = "space";
var image = frag.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
image.id = "pic";
image.className = "dell3";
image.setAttribute("src", f);

document.getElementById('case').appendChild(frag);
```

Note you probably want var keywords on the other variable assignments too as otherwise you'll create globals for each one implicitly.  I've added these to the example changes I made.  There are other optimisations you might want to make too, such as not doing the `document.getElementById()` lookup each time you loop (you can store it as a var outside of the loop).

Comment: Nice. it makes more sense now.